# How to create directory and file inside the same directory in ansible using single task

Tags: ansible

Is there any way to create directory and file inside the same directory in ansible using a single task? Currently, in my task, I'm creating a directory using a file module, state= directory. How to touch a file inside that directory in the same task?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html):

```
- name: Create a directory with a file inside
  file:
    path: "{{ item.path }}"
    state: "{{ item.state }}"
  loop:
    - { path: /tmp/foo, state: directory }
    - { path: /tmp/foo/bar.txt, state: touch }
```

Answer (score 1):

@Dom H has given it correctly i just wanted it to give it more convenient way in playbook.

the playbook will look like :

```
---
- name: Creating directory and files
  hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  become_user: root

  tasks:

  - name: Create a directory with a file inside
    file:
      path: "{{ item.path }}"
      state: "{{ item.state }}"
    loop:
      - { path: /tmp/foo, state: directory }
      - { path: /tmp/foo/bar.txt, state: touch }
```

and we can actually test before run it using:

```
 ansible-playbook -i localhost mkdir.yml --check
```