# Ansible create multiple directories and files within each directory

Tags: ansible

I am trying to create multiple directories (with different names) and files inside each directory.

I have a variable named directories that contains directory and file names like this:

```yaml
directories:
  - directory: dir1
    static_files: 
      files: 
        - file1
        - file2

  - directory: dir2
    static_files: 
      files: 
        - file1
        - file2
```

This is the workaround I was able to come up with using with_subelments but with two tasks which seems working. However, I believe there must be a solution with only one task to achieve this.

```yaml
- name: Creates directories
  file:
    path: "/tmp/{{ item[0].directory }}"
    state: directory
    recurse: yes
    mode: 0755
    owner: user
    group: group
  become: true
  with_subelements: 
    - "{{ directories }}"
    - static_files.files

- name: Creates files
  file:
    path: "/tmp/{{ item[0].directory }}/{{ item[1] }}"
    state: touch
    mode: 0644
    owner: user
    group: group
  become: true
  with_subelements: 
    - "{{ directories }}"
    - static_files.files
```

I might be missing a module that can do the job.
I also tried to leverage this solution without any luck [How to create directory and file inside the same directory in ansible using single task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60278142/how-to-create-directory-and-file-inside-the-same-directory-in-ansible-using-sing)

My question is, how can this be achieve, if possible, with a single task?
Any other solution and approach would also be great.

Expected result:

```
/tmp/dir1/file1
/tmp/dir1/file2
/tmp/dir2/file1
/tmp/dir2/file2
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create the structure

```yaml
  my_files: |
    {% filter from_yaml %}
    {% for dir in directories %}
    - [{{ dir.directory}}, directory]
    {% for file in dir.static_files.files %}
    - [{{ dir.directory }}/{{ file }}, touch]
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfilter %}
```

gives

```yaml
  my_files:
    - [dir1, directory]
    - [dir1/file1, touch]
    - [dir1/file2, touch]
    - [dir2, directory]
    - [dir2/file1, touch]
    - [dir2/file2, touch]
```

The iteration of the list

```yaml
    - file:
        path: "/tmp/{{ item.0 }}"
        state: "{{ item.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ my_files }}"
```

creates the directories and the files

```yaml
TASK [file] ***************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=['dir1', 'directory'])
changed: [localhost] => (item=['dir1/file1', 'touch'])
changed: [localhost] => (item=['dir1/file2', 'touch'])
changed: [localhost] => (item=['dir2', 'directory'])
changed: [localhost] => (item=['dir2/file1', 'touch'])
changed: [localhost] => (item=['dir2/file2', 'touch'])
```

```bash
shell> tree /tmp/dir1
/tmp/dir1
├── file1
└── file2

0 directories, 2 files
```

```bash
shell> tree /tmp/dir2
/tmp/dir2
├── file1
└── file2

0 directories, 2 files
```

This task is not idempotent. When you run it again the files will be *touched* and both the access and modification time will be updated. Set the parameters [*access_time*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html#parameter-access_time) and [*modification_time*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html#parameter-modification_time) to '*preserve*' if you don't want to change the times

```yaml
  my_files: |
    {% filter from_yaml %}
    {% for dir in directories %}
    - [{{ dir.directory}}, directory]
    {% for file in dir.static_files.files %}
    - [{{ dir.directory }}/{{ file }}, touch, preserve, preserve]
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfilter %}
```

gives

```yaml
  my_files:
    - [dir1, directory]
    - [dir1/file1, touch, preserve, preserve]
    - [dir1/file2, touch, preserve, preserve]
    - [dir2, directory]
    - [dir2/file1, touch, preserve, preserve]
    - [dir2/file2, touch, preserve, preserve]
```

Make the parameters *access_time* and *modification_time* optional

```yaml
    - file:
        path: "/tmp/{{ item.0 }}"
        state: "{{ item.1 }}"
        access_time: "{{ item.2|d(omit) }}"
        modification_time: "{{ item.3|d(omit) }}"
      loop: "{{ my_files }}"
```

This makes the task idempotent

```yaml
TASK [file] ***************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=['dir1', 'directory'])
ok: [localhost] => (item=['dir1/file1', 'touch', 'preserve', 'preserve'])
ok: [localhost] => (item=['dir1/file2', 'touch', 'preserve', 'preserve'])
ok: [localhost] => (item=['dir2', 'directory'])
ok: [localhost] => (item=['dir2/file1', 'touch', 'preserve', 'preserve'])
ok: [localhost] => (item=['dir2/file2', 'touch', 'preserve', 'preserve'])
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    directories:
      - directory: dir1
        static_files: 
          files: 
            - file1
            - file2
      - directory: dir2
        static_files: 
          files: 
            - file1
            - file2

    my_files: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for dir in directories %}
      - [{{ dir.directory}}, directory]
      {% for file in dir.static_files.files %}
      - [{{ dir.directory }}/{{ file }}, touch, preserve, preserve]
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: my_files

    - file:
        path: "/tmp/{{ item.0 }}"
        state: "{{ item.1 }}"
        access_time: "{{ item.2|d(omit) }}"
        modification_time: "{{ item.3|d(omit) }}"
      loop: "{{ my_files }}"
```

Comment: My man. What a golden answer.

Comment: What a nice and concise answer! This gives me new ideas how to work with Jinja2. Thanks @Vladimir Botka